# Dynamically push, pull, and set on mongoose schema update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to setup my patch api so that I can create a dynamic query to push, pull, and set data in my mongoose schema. I have plenty of values that I would change using set, but I also have an array of objects which would require me to call push when I need to insert and pull when I need to remove an item. I'm trying to find the best way to combine this into a dynamic structure.

Schema:

```
const StepSchema = new Schema({
    position: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    due_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    status: [{
        label: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Inactive', 'In Progress', 'Flagged', 'Complete'],
            default: 'Inactive'
        },
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users',
        },
        date: {
            type: Date
        }
    }],
    comments: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users',
            required: true
        },
        body: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
    }],

});
```

Api:

```
router.patch('/',
    async (req, res) => {

    let setQuery = req.body;
    let pushQuery = {};
    let pullQuery = {};

    //remove id from set query
    delete setQuery.id;

    //if there is a comment
    if(req.body.comment){
        pushQuery.comments = req.body.comment
    }

    //if I need to remove a comment
    if(req.body.remove_comment){
        pullQuery.comments = {_id: req.body.remove_comment.id}
    }


    //Push new status into array
    if(req.body.status) {
        pushQuery.status = {
            label: req.body.status,
            user: req.user._id,
            date: new Date()
        };

        delete setQuery.status;
    }

    //update step
    await Step.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {$set: setQuery, $push: pushQuery, $pull: pushQuery})
                .then(step => {
                        if(!step){
                            errors.noflow = "There was a problem updating the step";
                            return res.status(400).json(errors);
                        }
                        res.json(step)
                    })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(404).json(err);
                });




});
```

I've been getting the following error when trying to push a new status into my document:

> operationTime: Timestamp { *bsontype: 'Timestamp', low*: 1, high_:
>   1560978288 },   ok: 0,   errmsg: 'Updating the path \'status\' would
>   create a conflict at \'status\'',   code: 40,   codeName:
>   'ConflictingUpdateOperators',   '$clusterTime':    { clusterTime:
>   Timestamp { *bsontype: 'Timestamp', low*: 1, high_: 1560978288 },
>        signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: [Object] } },

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're doing that $set and $push on a status. Your pushQuery is trying to have `status` be an array on the document, and your setQuery wants to set it to whatever it was on the actual body (I'm guessing the same object.

A quickfix would be to remove it from the set object:

```
delete setQuery.status
```

A reasonable and stable way to do this would be to actually only take the things from req.body which you really want for each of the stages. Example:

```
const { position, name, dueDate, status, comment, remove_comment } = req.body;
const setQuery = { position, name, dueDate };
const pushQuery = { status, comments: comment };
// ...
```

That way your queries are not conflicting in any way.

Comment: I'm removing setQuery.status right after I add status to my pushQuery

Comment: Oh sorry, I've skipped that.